# Rails 4 - Destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have an industry model. It has has and belongs to many associations with each of my profile model and my organisation model.

The associations are:

industry.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :organisations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
```

organisation.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
```

profile.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

My schema has:

```
create_table "industries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "sector"
    t.string   "icon"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "industries_profiles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "industry_id"
    t.integer "profile_id"
  end

  add_index "industries_profiles", ["industry_id"], name: "index_industries_profiles_on_industry_id", using: :btree
  add_index "industries_profiles", ["profile_id"], name: "index_industries_profiles_on_profile_id", using: :btree
```

I have an index of industries, which I created in my development environment. I'm now trying to delete one.

When I click the delete link in my index, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in IndustriesController#destroy
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "industries_organisations" does  
not exist LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"industries_organisations... ^ :   
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid),  
a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef  
d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid =  
'"industries_organisations"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum
```

How do I delete the record?

Industries controller has:

```
class IndustriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_industry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /industries
  # GET /industries.json
  def index
    #@industries = Industry.all
    @industries = Industry.alphabetically
  end

  # GET /industries/1
  # GET /industries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /industries/new
  def new
    @industry = Industry.new
  end

  # GET /industries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /industries
  # POST /industries.json
  def create
    @industry = Industry.new(industry_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @industry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @industry, notice: 'Industry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @industry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @industry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /industries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /industries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @industry.update(industry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @industry, notice: 'Industry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @industry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @industry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /industries/1
  # DELETE /industries/1.json
  def destroy
    @industry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to industries_url, notice: 'Industry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_industry
      @industry = Industry.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def industry_params
      params.require(:industry).permit(:id, :sector, :icon)
    end
end
```

Comment: put up your code of the controller please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to build a `many to many` relationship, you need a relationship table `industries_organisations`. For more details, please read the doc here:

[Many to many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)